# Replace newlines with sed (a la tr)

Tags: sed

```
echo "hi,my,name,is" | sed 's/,/\n/g' >out.txt
```

yields:

```
hi
my
name
is
```

But in reverse:

```
sed 's/\n/,/g' out.txt
```

yields:

```
hi
my
name
is
```

Why doesn't `sed` revert the operation with an inversion of the replace operation?

Comment: because sed/awk strips the record separator (newline in your case) and adds back while printing... perl/ruby wont.. so you'd get your inversion there..

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
$ sed 'H;1h;$!d;x; s/\n/,/g' out.txt
hi,my,name,is
```

By default, sed reads in only one line at a time, processes it, and prints it.  Since a single line never has a newline character, the command `s/\n/,/g` does nothing.  The solution, as above, is to read the whole file in at once and then do `s/\n/,/g`.

The commands `H;1h;$!d;x` read the whole file in at once.  It is probably
simplest to think of this as an idiom.  If you really want to know
the gory details:

- `H` - Append current line to hold space
- `1h`  - If this is the first line, overwrite the hold space
  with it
- `$!d` - If this is not the last line, delete pattern space
  and jump to the next line.
- `x`  - Exchange hold and pattern space to put whole file in
  pattern space

#### Alternative: awk

```
$ awk 'NR>1{printf ","} {printf "%s",$0} END{print""}' out.txt
hi,my,name,is
```

Or:

```
$ awk '{printf "%s%s",(NR==1?"":","),$0} END{print""}' out.txt
hi,my,name,is
```

Comment: Or just `tr '\n' ,`

Comment: @Sparhawk Very true.  But, as you saw in the title of this question, the OP knew about the `tr` approach.  He was looking for a better understanding of `sed`.

Comment: Arrgghh, yes, true. I missed that, sorry. (+1)

Comment: Three more awk ways: `{printf "%s",t $0; t=","} END{print""}` or `{t=t "," $0} END{print substr(t,2)}` optionally with redundant `BEGIN{t=""}` or `-vt=` for clarity; or on condition none of the lines are empty `-vRS="" '{gsub(/\n/,","); print}'` (which is almost like the sed)

Answer (score 2):

With gnu sed

```
echo "hi,my,name,is" | sed 's/,/\n/g' | sed -z 's/\n/,/g'
```